# Enabling and disabling default behaviour on click

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a list with a header and some items. Clicking the header toggles the visibility of the items.

However, I would like to turn the header into a link, and for larger screen sizes this header shouldn't toggle the visibility of its sub items, but just act like a normal link.

I can't get this part to work. I have added return false/true, but it doesn't work. is there a better way to do this?

js:

```
var header = $('h3');
var list = $('ul');
var width = $(window).width();

header.click(function() {
    collapse(this);
});

var collapse = function (el) {
    if ($(window).width() < 699) {
        $(el).next().slideToggle();
        return false;
    } else {
        $(el).next().show();
        return true;
    }
};
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ao9cthg/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`event.preventDefault();`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to ignore link,

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ao9cthg/1/)**

```
header.click(function(e) {
    collapse(this,e);
});

var collapse = function (el,event) {
    if ($(window).width() < 699) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(el).next().slideToggle();

    } else {
        $(el).next().show();
    }
};
```

Also, I think the `else{..}` part won't be required as it anyways navigates to another link address.

Comment: Can you explain? According to your Q, if `<699` it should just display submenus right?

Comment: if <699, the h3 is used for toggling the list items. Above 699 the h3 (or the a href inside it) should open as a link...

Comment: So? my fiddle works then. Increase the output window size greater than 699 and Check this with fullscreen >699 https://jsfiddle.net/1ao9cthg/1/show/

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. It works as intended now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `window.matchMedia()` where it supports matching css media queries. For an example look at the following code.

```
var media = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 699px)");

media.addListener(function(m)}{
    header.unbind('click');
    if(m.matches){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(el).next().slideToggle();
    }
})
```

This will bind the respective click handler if the media query is hit by the js. Try it out and you would get the result you want. One flaw I saw in your code was, it would not re bind the events if user tries a fluid layout. Will only confuse.